# onClick Copy from drop down into a search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and I have been tasked with making an onclick function that takes the value from a drop down and inputs into a search box. Any advice on this would be much appreciated. I have listed below the code I currently have.

```
<script>
function populateSearch(e) {
  //alert('wibble')
  var $selector = $(e.target);
  var searchVal = $selector.attr('data-value');
  //alert($selector.attr('data-value'));

  var $originalSelects = $originalDiv.find('select');
}
</script>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="quickSearch dropdown-menu">
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="Goodbye Mo">option 1</li>
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="Hello Mo">option 2</li>
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="adios Mo">option 3</li>
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="Mo">option 4</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for providing me with some answers. My manager was able to give me some good advice and I have listed the solution he proposed below:

```
            <script>
        function populateSearch(e) {
            var $selector = $(e.target);
            var searchVal = $selector.attr('data-value');
             $('form[name="siteSearch"]').find('input#searchPhrase').val(searchVal);
            $('form[name="siteSearch"]').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. All you need to do is, add an input element, and then set its value using something like: `$("#myInput").val(searchVal);`

Here `myInput` is the ID of the input.

Also, notice that I've commented out the last line of code in your click handler. That is because `$originalDiv` variable is not defined in your Javascript. So leaving it there would result in an error.

```js
function populateSearch(e) {
  //alert('wibble')
  var $selector = $(e.target);
  var searchVal = $selector.attr('data-value');
  //alert($selector.attr('data-value'));

  $("#myInput").val(searchVal);
  //var $originalSelects = $originalDiv.find('select');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Dropdown Example
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
  <ul class="quickSearch dropdown-menu">
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="Goodbye Mo">option 1</li>
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="Hello Mo">option 2</li>
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="adios Mo">option 3</li>
    <li onclick="populateSearch(event);" data-value="Mo">option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//bind a click handler to all the lis
$('.quickSearch li').on('click', function(e){
  //get the attribute value off the li clicked and put it in the target value
  $('#target').val(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <ul class="quickSearch dropdown-menu">
    <li data-value="Goodbye Mo">option 1</li>
    <li data-value="Hello Mo">option 2</li>
    <li data-value="adios Mo">option 3</li>
    <li data-value="Mo">option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input type="text" id="target" value="">
```